# Sed : unknown option to `s'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im trying to change a config file by using bash script. Im using sed command to change as below.

```
VAR1=$(cat postgresql.conf | grep "shared_buffers =" | cut -d# -f1)
VAR2=$(shared_buffers = 8GB)
sed -ie s/${VAR1}/${VAR2}/g postgresql.conf
```

I tried but it gave  me error.

> sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'

What is missing?

Comment: Please, try use quote marks: `sed -ie "s/${VAR1}/${VAR2}/g" postgresql.conf`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that's not solved by a more simple substitution such as `sed -e '/shared_buffers /s/=[^#]*/= 8GB /'` or similar?

Comment: Tracing your script with `bash -x` should have indicated what you did wrong.

Comment: _sed -ie "s/${VAR1}/${VAR2}/\t/g" postgresql.conf_

Im using sed command as above and it works, however, the one that I changed become


_shared_buffers = 8GB# min 128kB_

how can I add a tab on it?
@TobySpeight

Comment: Answer updated with simpler command - that leaves the existing whitespace in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual cause is that one (or both) of your variables contains the delimiter (in your case `/`).  You can

- change the delimiter if you have an alternative character that won't be present:

  ```
  sed -e "s#${VAR1}#${VAR2}#g"
  ```

  or
- replace the delimiter in the variables:

  ```
  sed -e "s/${VAR1//\//\\/}/${VAR2//\//\\/}/g"
  ```

There may be other replacements you also need to make in `$VAR1` if you want it to match as a literal, as `s///` always uses regular expressions.

---

However, looking at what you have shown us, it appears that all you're really trying to do is change the value assigned to `shared_buffers` in the config file to the fixed value`8GB`, in which case there's no need for any variables:

```
sed -i -e '/^shared_buffers[ \t]/s/=[ \t]*[^# \t]\+/= 8GB/' /postgresql.conf
```

You can read that as *in every line that begins with `shared_buffers` and a horizontal space, then replace the first `=` and the word that follows with `= 8GB`*, which is what you seem to want.

Comment: It works by using 

'sed -ie "s/${VAR1}/${VAR2}/g" postgresql.conf '


how ever there's a line between it, it combine the changes I made with the line